# Django Delete Objects

Tags: python, django

I'm receiving this error "TemplateDoesNotExist at /bookmarks/list/1/delete_link/" when attempting to delete an object in Django.

In forms.py I have:

```
class DeleteForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Link
    fields = []
```

In views.py:

```
def delete_link(request, link_id):
    link_to_delete = get_object_or_404(Link, id=link_id)
    context_dict = {'link_id': link_id}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DeleteForm(request.POST, instance=link_to_delete)

        if form.is_valid():
            link_to_delete.delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('bookmarks/list')
    else:
        form = DeleteForm(instance = link_to_delete)
    template_vars = {'form': form}
    return render_to_response(request, 'bookmarks/delete_link.html', template_vars)
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^list/(?P<link_id>\w+)/delete_link/$', views.delete_link, name='delete_link'),
```

embedded in list.html (template for displaying a list of links, I want delete options next to each):

```
<a href='/bookmarks/list/{{ link.pk }}/delete_link/'> Delete</a>
```

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: The error message seems perfectly clear. Do you actually have that template?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
return render_to_response(request, 'bookmarks/delete_link.html', template_vars)
```

Django can't find your template. do you have it in your TEMPLATES_DIRS?